# Octave to Java - InitializeThetas Function

Tags: java, octave

Hi guys I´m new in java.
I'm trying to convert an octave function in to Java(using JBlas) but I´m not sure how to do this line:

```
OCTAVE: Thetas{i} = rand(sizes(i+1), sizes(i) + 1)*2*EPSILON-EPSILON;
```

My code in Java:

```
public class InitializeThetas {

    public static DoubleMatrix InitializeThetas(DoubleMatrix sizes, double epsilon)
    {
       int L= sizes.length;
       epsilon = 0.03;
       DoubleMatrix Thetas = new DoubleMatrix(new double[]{});
       Random r = new Random();

        for (int i = 1; i <= L - 1; i++) 
        {
            //Thetas{i} = rand(sizes(i+1), sizes(i) + 1)*2*EPSILON-EPSILON;

            Thetas.data[i]= r.nextInt() * 2 * epsilon - epsilon; 
        }
       return Thetas;
    } 
}
```

Comment: what is the problem you are having?

Comment: How can I convert this part rand(sizes(i+1), sizes(i) + 1) to java?

Comment: Not sure if I am reading this correctly. Is thetas supposed to be a 3 dimensional matrix?

Comment: No. Is a Bidemensional Matrix. But I´ve have no idea what rand(sizes(i+1), sizes(i) + 1) in octave does, sorry. I´m guessing is to random numbers on rows and columns, but i'm not sure.

Comment: The documentation is not good. My reading is that it will a return a matrix of dimensions (sizes(i+1), sizes(i)+1)

Comment: http://octave-online.net/ might be helpful

Comment: In octave the function rand receive 2 arguments. Rand(rows, columns).
This is my full function in octave:
function Thetas = initializeThetas ( sizes, EPSILON=0.03)


 L =length(sizes);
 
  for i = 1:L-1,
  Thetas{i} = rand(sizes(i+1), sizes(i) + 1)*2*EPSILON-EPSILON;
  
  end

 
end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this close to what you want?

```
public class InitializeThetas {

    public static Collection<DoubleMatrix> InitializeThetas(DoubleMatrix sizes, double epsilon)
    {
        int L= sizes.length;
        epsilon = 0.03;
        Collection<DoubleMatrix> Thetas = new ArrayList<DoubleMatrix>();

        for (int i = 0; i < L - 1; i++)
        {
            Thetas.add(DoubleMatrix.rand(Double.valueOf(sizes.get(i + 1)).intValue(), Double.valueOf(sizes.get(i)).intValue() + 1).mul(2).mul(epsilon).sub(epsilon));
        }
        return Thetas;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DoubleMatrix soze = new DoubleMatrix(10);
        for(int i = 0;i<10;i++){
            soze.put(i,i+1);
        }
        System.out.println(InitializeThetas(soze,1.1));
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks u are right, but I have a problem converting this line:
// octave Thetas{i} = rand(sizes(i+1), sizes(i) + 1)*2*EPSILON-EPSILON;

            Thetas.data[i]= r.nextInt() * 2 * epsilon - epsilon;

Comment: yesssss...Thanks @BevynQ  .You really helped a lot. Thank you very much... U solved my first problem =)